# Skip login page on Flutter app(Google + FireBase)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-signin

I am making a Flutter app and wish to make login through Google compulsory. I have integrated the login backend with the Login page. The app starts with a SplashScreen as the root directory and then comes to the login page. I am sending the login data as follows to the MainScreen. 
How do I skip Login page and directly go to the MainScreen if the user has already logged in?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'mainscreen.dart';
import 'showup.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:app_settings/app_settings.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  int dela = 500;
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

  Future<FirebaseUser> _signIn(BuildContext context) async {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text("Opening App..."),
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    ));

    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
      idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
    );

    FirebaseUser userDetails =
        (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    ProviderDetails providerInfo = new ProviderDetails(userDetails.providerId);

    List<ProviderDetails> providerData = List<ProviderDetails>();
    providerData.add(providerInfo);

    UserDetails details = UserDetails(
        userDetails.providerId,
        userDetails.displayName,
        userDetails.photoUrl,
        userDetails.email,
        userDetails.phoneNumber,
        providerData);

    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      CupertinoPageRoute(
          fullscreenDialog: true,
          builder: (context) => MainScreen(detailsUser: details)),
    );
    return userDetails;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 0, 15, 0),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 100,
                  ),
                  ShowUp(
                    delay: dela+2000,
                    child: ClipRRect(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.15),
                        child: SingleChildScrollView(
                          child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                              Center(
                                child: Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Welcome",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 25,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 30),
                              ClipRRect(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () async {
                                    try{
                                      final result = await InternetAddress.lookup('google.com');
                                      if(result.isNotEmpty && result[0].rawAddress.isNotEmpty) {
                                         _signIn(context)
                                      .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
                                      .catchError((e) => print(e));
                                      }
                                    }on SocketException catch (_) {
                                      showDialog(context: context,
                                        builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(23,28,28,28),
                                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                                          elevation: 10,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
                                          title: Text("Not Connected",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.white,
                                            fontSize: 18,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                           ),
                                          ),
                                          content: Text("You are not connected to the internet.\n\nCheck your connection and try again",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 14)),
                                          actions: <Widget>[
                                           FlatButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        Navigator.pop(context);
                                      },
                                      child: Text("Cancel",
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                      ),)
                                    ),
                                    FlatButton(
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        AppSettings.openDataRoamingSettings();
                                      },
                                      child: Text("Network Settings",
                                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),)
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                        ));
                                    }

                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    width: 210,
                                    height: 50,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    child: Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                          MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        CircleAvatar(
                                          child: Image.asset(
                                              'Assets/google-logo.png'),
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          radius: 10,
                                        ),
                                        SizedBox(width: 10),
                                        Text("Continue with Google"),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 30,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class UserDetails {
  final String provDet;
  final String userName;
  final String photoURL;
  final String userEmail;
  final String userPhone;
  final List<ProviderDetails> providerData;
  UserDetails(this.provDet, this.userName, this.photoURL, this.userEmail,
      this.userPhone, this.providerData);
}

class ProviderDetails {
  ProviderDetails(this.providerDetails);
  final String providerDetails;
}
```

I have searched StackOverFlow for answers but did not find exactly how to send the UserDetails to the mainscreen without signing in through the LoginPage.
Is there anyway to get this done without scrapping this whole code?

**EDIT**

This is how mainscreen.dart looks

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'login.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser;

  MainScreen({Key key, @required this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: Column (
      children: <Widget>[
      Text(widget.detailsUser.userName),
      Text(widget.detailsUser.userEmail), //basically accessed using widget.detailsUser.whatever
      ]),
      );
     }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) save data to sharedpreferences when used login first time

2) in splachscreen check user is login or not,if login, get data from sharedpreferences and pass to mainScreen

here is demo ...

```
 var islogin = // put your logic to check user is already login or not

              if(islogin){
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => MainScreen(detailsUser: details),
                  ),
                );
              }else{
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Login(),
                  ),
                );
              }
```

Comment: this is, probably the only solution that will work for me, but i did **not** want to use shared preferences or secured storage or any form of local storage.Is there anyway to not use local storage?  But this works. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Use currentUser() method of FirebaseAuth [(firebase_auth_plugin)](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth) class in initState(). it will give you current user information.
it checks current user is null or not, that means logged in already or not?
I mean if user is null means not logged in & if not null means logged in already.

```
 await firebaseAuth.currentUser().then((user){ // firebaseUser user
 if(user !=null){
    Navigator.pushReplacement(
      context,
      CupertinoPageRoute(
          fullscreenDialog: true,
          builder: (context) => MainScreen(detailsUser:user)), //navigate your main screen.
    );
 }
}).catchError((e){
print("error:$e");
});
```

Comment: i tried this, but am getting two errors 1)currentUser can't be accessed using static access. 2) The argument type 'FirebaseUser' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'UserDetails

Comment: Okay then what is your 'UserDetails' type?

Comment: UserDetails is a class. I've defined it at the end

Comment: No no,i'm taking about the detailsUser argument  which you defined in MainScreen class . Could you please share MainScreen class code too?

Comment: `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'loginpage.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final UserDetails detailsUser;

  MainScreen({Key key, @required this.detailsUser}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainScreenState createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold( body: Column(children: <widget>[ Text(widget.detailsUser.userName), Text(widget.detailsUser.userEmail)] ),);}  `

Comment: basically, constructer(@required this.detailsUser).... then use it as widget.detailsUser.photoURL, etc

Answer (score 1):

since its a google sign in, I would recommend passing in Auth object which you get from firebase to the sign-in page, if its null then u can show sign-in page else redirect to main screen.

Comment: can u please make an example code snippet? thank you